# Passing post data from one form to second form in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a simple lead collection form that asks for the user's zip code on the first page, and then based on which state that zip code is in it sends them to the second page of my form with the zip code already populated, or to another site. In my pre-CodeIgniter days this was a very simple thing to do, but I'm not sure how to send the zip code data from my routing script to the second page of my form and not have it mess with CI's form validation. The second page of my form currently looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="zip"value="<?php echo set_value('zip'); ?>" />
```

So if the user submits invalid data on the second page, the form reloads with all the data pre-populated (using CI's set_value function). But what needs to happen is something like...

IF the user comes from page 1 of the form, populate the zip code field using the data from form 1. ELSE, re-populate it after a failed form submit.

Is there some way for set_value to intelligently work in both situations? If not, do I need to use a different function? I'm also not sure how to pass the zip code data from my routing script to the controller for page 2 of the form.

I'd really appreciate any help. THANK YOU!!